# Matlab saving for loop data

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, save

I have a function like

```
 for i = 1:n
     [A,B] = generatecomp(i, a, b);
 end
```

and I want to save these A and B values which are n x 1 matrices.
I tried to solve the problem using the following code:

```
A=[];
B=[];
    for i=1:n
    [A1,B1] = generatecomp(i, a, b);
    A=[A;A1]
    B=[B,B1]
    end
save('ABval.mat','A','B')
```

bu the problem is the length of the matrice changes with 'n' value. How can I save all A and B values in the same .mat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all intermediate values of `A` and `B` saved in the file, then you will need to place your `save` call *within* your for loop.

```
for k = 1:n
    [A1,B1] = generatecomp(k, a, b);
    A=[A,A1]
    B=[B,B1]
    filename = sprintf('ABval%d.mat', k);
    save(filename, 'A', 'B')
end
```

Or if you want them all in the same file, then you can store intermediate values within a cell array (which has the added benefit that they don't have to necessarily be the same dimensions) and then save the entire cell array to the file.

```
% Cell arrays to store intermediate values
A = cell(1, n);
B = cell(1, n);

for k = 1:n
    [A{k}, B1{k}] = generatecomp(k, a, b);
end

save('ABvals.mat', 'A', 'B')
```

Comment: sorry I wrote it wrong here. it's in loop. the problem is the sizes of As and Bs are different and it says 

Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

My question is how can I fix it

Comment: @user70299 that error is likely because you wrote `[A;A1]` rather than `[A,A1]` (note the semicolon vs comma)

Comment: @user70299 my second solution would solve this issue as well.